# handle URL's with a given scheme when the app is already openend

Tags: codenameone

*Note for the readers: **this question is Codename One specific**.*

The following code allows me to detect if my app was openend by a link with a given scheme (using the build hints described the article "[Intercepting URL's On iOS & Android](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intercepting-urls-on-ios-android.html)"):

```
    String arg = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);
    if (arg != null) {
        Dialog.show("Display Arg", arg, "OK", "CANCEL");
    }
```

The problem is that it works only if the app wasn't already opened. How can I 
detect an url with an already opened app in a simple use case like the following?

- The user inserts their data in the app
- The app uses an external service to send a confirmation email. That email contains a link with a custom protocol, like `myapp://verificationCode=1234`
- The user opens the email *(without manually killing the Codename One app, that remains in the background)* and then taps the link
- The app goes from background to foreground and does something with the `verificationCode`: **the problem is that this step works only if the app was killed by the user before tapping the link.**

Any code solution?

Comment: To complete the question: in my app all the `Forms` extend a `CustomBaseForm`, so my idea is that the code to intercept the URLs should be inserted in the `CustomBaseForm` to make this functionality always available... but, as I explained in the question, this solution doesn't work. Does it exist a listener to intercept URLs in any moment, not only at app startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` should be invoked every time you come back to foreground. Notice that the first lines of the default start implementation check if there is a current form and if so send you back to it.

You need to have that code before that special case and handle the case of returning to foreground with an argument correctly.